# kibana issues with reporting timeouts

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I have following issue,
I have quite big index and when users are trying to perform csv reports with filters even, I see warnings that reports are timedout and not completed:

[image]

I tried to adapt configuration of kibana.yml with:

```
xpack.reporting.queue.timeout: 400m 
xpack.reporting.csv.maxSizeBytes: 60000000
```

but the results are the same,
Can someone please pick to me an idea what can I do with it ?
I'm thinking also if there is possibility to perform report directly from elasticsearch api using link but I cannot find anything.